# How to file tax for the sale of stocks from form 1099B?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, form-1099

Last year I sold 100 shares of one of my stocks in ONE order. However, I didn't buy those shares at the same time. They were from multiple purchases at different times (around 7 times). In my 1099B form, Fidelity shows profits for each of the separate purchase, plus the total profit for the whole 100 shares.

So my question is when I file tax, do I report the sale of 100 shares as a single entry, OR do I have to report individual purchases separately, which will be very tedious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You report each position separately. You do this on [form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf). 7 positions is nothing, it will take you 5 minutes.

There's a tip on form 8949 that says this, though:

For Part I (short term transactions):

> **Note**. You may aggregate all short-term transactions reported on
>   Form(s) 1099-B showing basis was reported to the IRS and for which no
>   adjustments or codes are required. Enter the total directly on
>   Schedule D, line 1a; you are not required to report these transactions
>   on Form 8949 (see instructions).

For Part II (long term transactions):

> **Note**. You may aggregate all long-term transactions reported on Form(s)
>   1099-B showing basis was reported to the IRS and for which no
>   adjustments or codes are required. Enter the total directly on
>   Schedule D, line 8a; you are not required to report these transactions
>   on Form 8949 (see instructions).

If the 1099B in your case shows basis for each transaction as reported to the IRS - you're in luck, and don't have to type them all in separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your like-kind (same symbol, ST/LT) stock positions, just be sure that your totals match the total dollar amounts on the 1099.  An inconsistency will possibly result in a letter from IRS to clarify.

So, if you sold the 100 shares, and they came from 7 different buys, list it once.  The sell price and date is known, and for the buy price, add all the buys and put "**Various**" for the date.

If you have both long term and short term groups as part of those 7 buys, split them into two groups and list them separately.

Comment: No, you cannot group them unless 1099B reports purchase price per position. This is plain wrong.